# If you guess that a person's hair is curly (when their head is covered) and you later see that the person's hair is curly, how would say that?

Tags: sentence-construction

Are all the below options grammatically correct?

> 1. I knew/guessed your hair **would be** curly.
> 2. I knew/guessed you **had** curly hair.
> 3. I knew/guessed you **would have** curly hair.

In option 2, does **had** imply that the person **had** curly hair and doesn't **have** curly hair?

Comment: Yes, you can literally interpret #2 that way. Most people aren't pedantic about that though. They're all generally correct although I think #2 is actually the one I would probably prefer.

Answer (score 1):

All of those are grammatical, and the  only fact stated by those sentences which use the verb **guess** is a fact about your guess; they say nothing factual, one way or another, about his or her hair.

On the other hand, **knew** implies that the experience of seeing the hair corroborates the thought you had about it.

That said, in speech (as distinct from writing), you could give **guessed** an intonation that conveys the idea "and I was correct in my guess!" or you could give **curly** an intonation that conveys the idea "and I was wrong in my guess!"

> I GUESSED you would have curly hair.  [I was right]
>   I guessed you would have CURLY hair.  [I was wrong]

Comment: "as I had guessed" or "as I thought you would be".

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using "so" to avoid repetition.

Comment: **as** already conveys the idea contained in **so**.  Your construction is not idiomatic.

Comment: So option 2 doesn't imply that the person **had and doesn't have** curly hair, right?

Comment: Which version of option 2?

Comment: 'I guessed you had curly hair.'

Comment: If you are looking at the person as you say these words, "I knew you had curly hair", it could fit the following contexts: a)  Even though you are bald now, I knew that as a youth your hair was curly. or b) Now that I see that you have curly hair under that hat, I can say I was right to think your hair was curly.

Comment: Unless you intone **guessed** in a certain manner, or **curly** in a certain manner, the sentence with **guessed** makes no factual statement about the hair. It states only that you had made a guess, and we do not know whether that guess was right or wrong.

Comment: In speech, it is the actual context and the intonation given the words that resolves the ambiguity between potential contexts like A and potential contexts like B, either of which would be possible when examining the statement not *in situ* but *in vitro*.